# Plotting boundary value expression against a parameter

Tags: plotting

I am very new to *Mathematica* and have a question regarding plotting a ODE boundary value problem.

Let say I have an ODE

```
alpha = 1/2;
beta = -5;
eq = beta*f'''[x] + alpha*f[x]*f'[x] == 0
bc = {f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f'[10] == 1}; 
NDSolve[{eq, bc}, f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

I want to plot `alpha*f''[0] + (f''[0])^3` vs `beta`. In the plot, `beta` should take the range [-5, 5]. `NDSolve` should use shooting method for the numerical solution.

Also, how I can extract data from that plot as a .txt file.

Comment: Could you try to write down some Mathematica code?

Comment: No idea how to write mathematica code here. Sorry mate

Comment: you can take infinity to be some thing like 10 or 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete solution as some issues remain. but may be will help you get started, as I have to go.

There is some issues when beta is takes some values (between -1 and 1). NDSolve complains for some values of beta.

```
Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision \
within 100 iterations.
```

This generates the plot you wanted, but you might have to play with NDSolve options or make sure your parameters are ok.

```
y[beta_] := 
  Module[{eq, sol, x, f, bc, max = 10, alpha = 0.5, r}, 
   eq = beta*f'''[x] + alpha*f[x]*f'[x] == 0;
   bc = {f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f'[max] == 1};
   sol = First@NDSolve[{eq, bc}, {f[x], f'[x], f''[x]}, {x, 0, max}];
   r = f''[x] /. sol /. x -> 0;
   alpha*r + beta*r^3];
data = Table[{beta, y[beta]}, {beta, -5, 5, 1}];
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y(beta)", None}, {beta, "y[beta] vs. beta"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: data = Table[{lambda, y[lambda]}, {lambda, -5, 0, 1}];

Comment: Trying to plot alpha*r + beta*r^3 vs lambda here. Can we use shooting method?

Comment: I wanted the answer you already give me but I am unable to execute the code. STill I got an error. Could you please upload ur .nb file?
As for as the change is concern, I was hope to give an ode with which NDsolve may have no issue.